# How to write ${n \choose k}$ as a sum of integers not using the division operator?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Assume $n>k>0$ are integers.

We know that ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is an integer.

Can we find $f(n,k)$ and some sets $I,J \subset \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $\sum_{i \in I, j \in J} f(i,j) = {n \choose k}$ where $f(n,k) \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and is written without the division operator (i.e. not a composition of functions including the division operator)?

Also, $I,J$ can not be defined using the division operator or any function that is a composition of it (avoiding trivial cases like $I = \{1,2, \dots, {n \choose k}\}, f(n,k) = 1$)

In a similar case we know $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is an integer and it can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^ni = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ i.e without the division operator.

Can we do a similar trick here?

Edit: adding some constraints to the question so it can be interpreted only in one way:

(1) $f:N_1 \times N_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $N_1,N_2 \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$

(2) $f$ is some composition of some or all of the following operators: identity, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and power, where power is restricted to $\mathbb{Z}_{>0} \times \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ domain.

(3) $I \subseteq N_1, J \subseteq N_2$

(4) $I,J$ can be defined without usage of a function, or with a functions staisfying (2)

Comment: $\sum i(i+1)/2 = n(n+1)(n+2)/6$. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

$${ n\choose r } = \sum_{k=0}^{r} {n-r \choose k}{r \choose r-k} $$

This can be easily proved using a combinatorial argument. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Combinatorial_proof).

Here is one more called [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) which states that $$ {n \choose r} = \sum_{i=r-1}^{n-1} {i \choose r-1 }$$

Comment: I am guessing that ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ "uses division operator" and hence is not allowed under the sum. Only $\frac{n!}{k!}$ or $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ would be because one can make explicit cancellations.

Comment: Note that if we define ${n \choose k}$ as number of ways to choose $k$ objects out of $n$ objects  then it can be easily seen that ${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k } + {n-1 \choose k-1}$ and ${n \choose n} = {n \choose 0} =1$ which does not use any 'division operator'. So we can calculate  ${n \choose k}$, just by adding integers recursively.Alternatively if we define  ${n \choose k}$ as the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ then also we do not use any 'division operator' since the coefficients in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ will be integers for sure.